# Chain selectors for custom module styling in Next JS not working

Tags: css, next.js

Chaining selectors in css file doesn't seem to apply styles. I am importing the styles in the component and it only applies for the main class, for example:

```
import styles from './Home.module.css'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <header className={styles.header}>
      <div className={styles.headerContainer}>
...
```

and than in Home.module.css I have:

```
.header {
  // some styles that are getting applied
}
.header .headerContainer {
 //some styles that don't show up
}
```

On the page I am able to see header that is styled but not the headerContainer. So I understand that Next js automatically adds some variables to the end of the classes when passing styles item to jsx but trying to understand how I would chain the selectors in css and be able to use styles in such way in Next JS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find a solution?

So far, I just use `:global` to get around it. I'm not sure how it works, but I assume it has a similar effect as `!important`.

What I want to do:

```
.section.with-banner {
  ...styles
}
```

In Next.js CSS module using `:global`:

```
.section:global.with-banner {
  ...styles
}
```

Probably only a short-term fix, but I hope this helps.